# What is the sentence structure of "Divergent as the arguments are, It is my firm conviction that..."?

Tags: sentence-structure, inversion

> What is the sentence structure of "Divergent as the arguments are, It is my firm conviction that..."?

Is it a correct sentence? It seems like an inversion but I can't find this structure online. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generally, this stylistic "device" uses *as*.[adjective or adverb]...*as*

**As** funny **as** the actors were, I didn't like the play.

2. So, the sample sentence in standard English would be:

**As divergent as** the arguments are, it is my firm conviction [that etc.].

However, in speech (spoken language), the first **as** is often left out.

1. *as funny as* (above) has the same **semantic meaning** as **even though (although)**:

Even though the actors were funny, I didn't like the play.
or
The actors may have been funny to a certain extent, but I didn't like the play.

as [adjective or adverb] as [verbal phrase].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. It is one way of adding a *concessive clause*.

Other examples of a concessive clause:

- It is my firm conviction that [x is true], **even though** the arguments are divergent.
- It is my firm conviction that [x is true], **despite the fact** the arguments are divergent.

You can also put the concessive clause at the beginning of the sentence:

- **Despite** the arguments being divergent, it is my firm conviction that [x is true].

What makes the construction in your example different among the others is that the use of the adverb "as" suggests there are *gradations* of divergence:

- Divergent **as** the arguments **are**, It is my firm conviction that [x is true].

For example, if someone said "as much as I am enjoying myself, I must leave", it would suggest that they are *very much* enjoying themselves, to the point that leaving is a difficult decision.

Comment: How does my example suggest gradations of divergence?

Comment: @LearningMathematics the adverb 'as' is used to indicate a degree, or amount. For example, if someone said "as much as I like you, I won't help you", it suggests that they like the person to a certain degree.